# ie shows things backwards? how to fix

Tags: css, internet-explorer

i have an ie problem for some reason my tabbed menu shows the opposite way in ie than it should 
it should have tabs on the top right and tabs on the left side of the container but only in ie the tabs appear on the right hand side i cant seem to figure it out

here is my html lists , some script and the css applied to them

```
<ul>
    <li class="dealer tabbed"><a>Manufacturer Dealer</a></li>
    <li class="lender tabbed"><a>Lender<br />&nbsp</a></li>
    <li class="developer tabbed"><a>Developer<br />&nbsp</a></li>
 </ul>

<ul class="side">
    <li class="overview tab"><a>Overview</a></li>
    <li class="tour tab"><a>Take the tour</a></li>
    <li class="websites tab"><a>Example websites</a></li>
    <li class="faq tab"><a>FAQ</a></li>
    <li class="support tab"><a>Support</a></li>
</ul>

  <div id="mainContainer">
        <div class="div1 hide">
            overview
        </div>
        <div class="div2 hide">
            take the tour</div>
        <div class="div3 hide">
            example websites</div>
        <div class="div4 hide">
            faq</div>
        <div class="div5 hide">
            support</div>
```

repeated for each sidetab

```
 $(".overview").click(function () {
    $(".hide").hide();
    $(".div1").show();
    $(".tab").addClass("inactive");
    $(".overview").removeClass("inactive");
    $(".overview").addClass("active");
```

repeated for each top tab

```
$(".dealer").click(function () {
    $(".hide").hide();
    $(".div1").show();
    $(".tabbed").addClass("inactive");
    $(".dealer").removeClass("inactive");
    $(".dealer").addClass("active");
```

CSS:

```
#container {
    position:relative;
}

#mainContainer {
    left:130px;
    position:absolute;
    top:73px;
}



.div1, .div2, .div3, .div4, .div5, .welcome {
    position:relative;
    bottom:100px;
    top:0px;
}

    .topnav ul li a {
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: Could you please fix the formatting? And what is .topnav and the other elements in that css? Also, if you're really serious that that JS is "repeated for each tab".. ouch. Should be easy to do for all tabs in one go.

Comment: i would post an image but it wont let me ok so i have a container above the container there is a list of 3 links going horozontal at the left hand side going vertical there is another list of 5 links (.side) i previously asked if there was a shorter way to do the javascript and that was the answer i got

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i found out the problem it was just that ie needed a left:0; adding to the css this seemed to have fixed my problem